# Java foreach loop not finding existing list element

Tags: java, foreach

I am looping through a collection of `Parameter` objects, looking for `Parameter.name = "Code"`. If I can't find it I default to the first Parameter in the list, as below:

```
    header = WBMessageFactory.getWBMessageDescriptor(Configuration.getWBHeaderIDString());

    for (Parameter p : header.getSegment().getParameter()) {
        if (p.getName() == "Code") {
            String wbCode = raw.substring(p.getStartPosition().intValue(), p.getLength().intValue());
            logger.info("Found WB code... " + wbCode);
            body = WBMessageFactory.getWBMessageDescriptor(wbCode);
            break;  
        }
    }

    if (body == null) {
        Parameter p = header.getSegment().getParameter().get(0);
        logger.error("Could not find Code parameter in Header template, using " + p.getName());
        body = WBMessageFactory.getWBMessageDescriptor(raw.substring(p.getStartPosition().intValue(), p.getLength().intValue()));
    }
```

As you can see, I log the `Parameter` name when I can't find Code. **Occasionally**, logging reveals the following:

```
Could not find Code parameter in Header template, using Code
```

Can anyone explain what the heck is going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
 if (p.getName() == "Code") {
```

You probably meant to say

```
 if (p.getName().equals("Code")) {
```

The first one [compares the *string reference*](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/strings/12stringcomparison.html), which is almost certainly not what you want. The second one compares the *contents* of the string.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is in the following line:

```
if (p.getName() == "Code")
```

To check for String equality you have to use equals.

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing the strings with `==`, you should use `equals()`. If you [`intern`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) both of the strings, you could compare them with `==`, but interned Strings are retained by the JVM for a long time which could be considered a memory leak, and the microoptimisation probably isn't of benefit very often.

Comment: You should never* intern Strings yourself. (*) For experts: almost never. It could lead to memory leaks if used in the wrong way.

Comment: @Mark: Thanks, I'll rephrase the answer to discourage that.